# MVVM Data Binding without Control

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am using C#, XAML, and MVVMLight to create an MVVM application but I am having problems with how to bind data from the ViewModel to the Model without it displaying on a control. For example I have a database in the Model that I need to determine if it exists and has valid data. I make this available from the ViewModel and I just want to bind the value (could be a boolean, string, or whatever) to the code for the View in the background without it showing up on a XAML control (sort of like a resource). The problem is that I can't figure out how to do this.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <system:String x:Key="StringId" Text="{Binding Text}" />
</Page.Resources>
```

Text is a field provided by the data context and it would also possibly work if there was an easy way to access a value of the data context without using any includes from the ViewModel folder.

Comment: You can't bind the property Text from ViewModel to View? Or Aren't you take data from View to ViewModel?

Comment: How do I bind a property to the view so that XAML can handle the references and I can access it from the code of the view? As far as I can tell it would work to just bind the data to an invisible text-block, but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to bind the property to Static Resource in Xaml not have sense. Because, when you create static resource is that you don't want repeat the same variable in your xaml. But this objective is possible with binding, the difference is with that binding from ViewModel you can modify this property from code.

Now if you want have property that can be modified from ViewModel, simply where you need bind:

And in your code:

```
private string _property;
public string Property
    {
        get { return _property; }
        set { _property= value; RaisePropertyChanged("Property"); }
    }
```

But you want a property in xaml:

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <System:String x:Key="Property">Text</System:String>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

And the Binding will be:

```
<Label Content="{StaticResource Property}"/>
```

Comment: So what would be the proper way of getting the resource now from the XAML .cs file? The goal of this whole binding is to access a property from the ViewModel from the View without it showing up on a control and without any unnecessary references between the View and ViewModel.

Comment: If you want have available the property in Xaml and ViewModel you must do my first option. If you only want available property in Xaml use second option.
I don't see what others cases can be.